# Scrapy Crawl Page and Supage but crawls only one item

Tags: python, scrapy

I Have an issue with my Spider. I tried to follow some tutorial to understand the scrapy a little bit better and extended the tutorial to crawl also subpages. The issue of my spider is that it only crawls one element of the entry page and not 25 as it should be on the page.

I have no clue where the failure is. Perhaps somebody of you can help me here:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import scrapy
from reddit.items import RedditItem

class PostSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'post'
    allowed_domains = ['reddit.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        reddit_urls = [
            ('datascience', 'week')
        ]

        for sub, period in reddit_urls:
            url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/' + sub + '/top/?sort=top&t=' + period
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # get the subreddit from the URL
        sub = response.url.split('/')[4]

        # parse thru each of the posts
        for post in response.css('div.thing'):
            item = RedditItem()
            item['title'] = post.css('a.title::text').extract_first()
            item['commentsUrl'] = post.css('a.comments::attr(href)').extract_first()

            ### scrap comments page.
            request = scrapy.Request(url=item['commentsUrl'], callback=self.parse_comments)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            return request


    def parse_comments(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['commentsText'] = response.css('div.comment div.md p::text').extract()
        self.logger.info('Got successful response from {}'.format(response.url))
        yield item
```

Thanks for your help.
BR

Comment: Do `yield request` instead of `return request` ...

Comment: yeah, you have to `yield request` instead of `return request` in parse method, because it stops the code flow in for loop

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your comments:
Indeed I have to yield request it, rather return request.
Now it is working.